# How to enable mining in a new network?

Tags: nodeos, mainnet, network

I need to start a new mainnet network and start mining without voices.
How can I do that?

I do not quite understand how testnet and mainnet work, but I know for sure that I need to run mainnet on my genesis separately from the main.
My mining does not work, and I do not know how to run it.

Comment: Please add some more information, what are you trying to accomplish and why? What do you mean without voices? And when you say 'mainnet' do you mean a single node testnet or is this a network you'd like other Block Producers to be apart of?

Comment: I added additional information.
I need all the mainnet startup commands with mining

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to run a **single node test net**. 
Try not to confuse it with the *main net* as that's the popular EOSIO based Blockchain with Block Producers like EOS New York or Genereos.

To start your own single node test net you're best off reading the docs found here at https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/ I highly recommend using the Docker quickstart as you'll be able to re-create new blockchains very easily.

Also **Mining** is done on Proof of Work consensus, not Delegated Proof of Stake, therefore, Mining does not exist on EOSIO based chains.

Comment: I correctly understand that I can not extract blocks in mainnet.
Is there information where this restriction is written in the code to remove?

Comment: What do you mean by 'extract' blocks? Like remove them?

Comment: Delete the rules under which I can extract blocks in mainnet
I want to run the coins in a separate network and try to understand how I can do it.
You can call it fork but without changing the genesis of the block.
I also want to create such names as eosio and eos.token

Comment: I think you're asking this: is there a way to fork the mainnet in a way that gives your nodes the ability to produce and gives you control over the eosio account.

Comment: Do you know the answer to how this can be done?

Comment: Yes. The community's not ready for that information. The current set of community-written web clients trust arbitrary JSON RPC endpoints without verification. If I make an easy guide to forks then scammers will use it to trick web clients.

Comment: Then how do I know this information or when?

Comment: I'm probably going to wait releasing this information until I implement this GH issue and web apps have had time to adopt it: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs2/issues/1 .

Comment: Well, I will also wait for your reply

Comment: @ToddFleming any news on this?

Comment: @confused00 not yet.